# Mutually Exclusive sign in using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have created two Devise models Admin and User. Everything works as I planned. Users sign in using the path `...\users\sign_in`, admins sign in using `...\admins\sign_in`.

However, when a normal user signs in and then (without sign out) an admin signs in, I have two signed in users.
I understand that one of the possible ways to do it is override session controller and check before sign in whether or not there is already signed in user. But I want to do without overriding if possible.

Is there any other way to do it? For example maybe there is some configuration parameters restricting more than one users to be signed in in the system.

Comment: This is something I'd love to learn too!!

Comment: In the meantime I'll try to override the session controller and see how it works.